# How to style my View to wrap the contents inside

Tags: react-native

Let me preamble this by saying I'm new to react-native

Here is my component:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class CountryCodeInput extends Component {
  state = { text: '' }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  onTextChange(text) {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(text) || text === "") {
     this.setState({ text })
    }
    // this.props.onTextChange(text)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", marginRight: 0, backgroundColor: 'red', alignSelf:'baseline', flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
      <Text style={{backgroundColor:"yellow"}}>+</Text>
        <TextInput 
        onChangeText={(text)=>this.onTextChange(text)} 
        maxLength={3} 
        keyboardType="numeric"
        style={{backgroundColor:"grey", borderBottomColor: 'black', borderBottomWidth: 1, fontSize: 16, height: 24, width: 36, paddingVertical: 4 }}
        value={this.state.text} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default CountryCodeInput
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

I need to remove all the red portion, and limit the height of the yellow section to the height of the grey section. How can I do this?

`alignSelf:'baseline'` and `flexWrap: "wrap"` dont seem to help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove flex from your style

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginRight: 0, backgroundColor: 'red', alignSelf:'baseline', flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
```

Comment: Ok that works, thanks. Could you please explain when `flex: 1` should be used, then?

Comment: `flex: 1` means take all the available space, if you have two views with `flex: 1`, they'll take 50% of the available space.